# Back space is not working while validating a textbox to numeric

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I'm using JavaScript to validate a textbox to accept only Numbers.

My code as bellow :

```
onkeypress="return ( event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57);"
```

Now if I typed 120 and want to change it to 50, so I want to delete 120 and put new value 50 but back space is not working.

It works in Google Chrome, but not in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `event.keyCode`, for more support, do something like this: `var key=event.keyCode||event.charCode`.

Comment: @SamusHands if it needed to be changed to `keyCode` then there wouldn't be a problem in the first place, because the above code wouldn't work at all. (Though you're right that the `event` details do vary between browsers.)

Comment: [My Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33198599/5305938) works in both Mozilla, and Chrome. Tested on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kszzzxr/).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
onkeypress="var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode; return ((key  >= 48 && key  <= 57) || key == 8);";
```

This allows any number key (`48` to `57`) and the backspace key (`8`). This also adds more support by using `keyCode` for the key code and `charCode` as fallback. JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kszzzxr/

Comment: Great, it runs well fast.

Answer (score 1):

Well, well, I think you'd just must run a function when the textbox value changes, I use a match to keep just numbers in the textbox value.

```
textbox.value=textbox.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig,'');
/* From 0 to 9 (just numbers) */
```

And this is a way more supported, but it may delay few ms to remove the letters...

It's very dangerous to someone paste some letters in textbox, then you use onkeyup/down, onpaste or the big onchange that will easily, and if possible, you could keep this event in some script tag/file.

Everyone can jump your code, then if you use server-side for this validation, make just numbers allowed with reg.

Answer (score 0):

this will work on all browsers..
first get the right event

```
var key = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : event.which;
```

the use it

```
return (key  >= 48 && key  <= 57 || key ==8);
```

try this, add the keycode of the backspace explicitly
http://jsfiddle.net/m22zzc51/1/

Comment: [This has exactly the same problem that the code in the OP has.](http://jsfiddle.net/m22zzc51/)

Comment: You can simply use `||`.